# Overloading browser's window object - Will it cause performance issues?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, browser

I am integrating different third paty tools with my project say newrelic, branchIO etc.., I am loading all of its js in the window object.

Currently i am trying to use one of the internationalization libraries. I have 2 plans.
1)To load the (en/es)translation-keys.json (a file which has key value pairs where values are the texts in corresponding languages) on window object.
2)To load the file in my application's globalState.

Also i have plans to add more 3rd party tools which would be loaded in the window object in future.

My question is, Will overloading browser's window object with many files cause performance issue? If it is so, is there any other way to improve the performance?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using HTML and js you can use defer and async to control when and how the file.js can load.
and for a more advanced option, you can create the import of js file with js

```
    const script = document.createElement('script');

// ️ local file
// script.setAttribute('src', 'another-file.js');

// ️ remote file
script.setAttribute(
  'src',
  'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js',
);

script.setAttribute('async', '');
```

and that with the concept of (async, await, and promise) you can have full control of how & when to load your files.

Comment: Yes thats right. Currently i am also doing dynamic import only. But my question is what if i need some x files (eg: 15 files) in window object and each of the files is doing its job at one time. Will it cause any performance issue than keeping those files in global state.

Comment: I don't think there is a general answer for that because it depends on the size of the file and the speed of the server you are going to use and the speed of the internet the user is going to have.